# XMLMapper not showing result in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, mapping, alamofire, xmlmapper

I'm facing an issue where i cannot get the responseData from XMLMapper (objectmapper) to a UITableView. Tableview shows 5 empty cells. Could anyone help me out on this issue?

I'm trying to accomplish a tableview where the IDNR (String) is displayted as label and the Validity is displayed as DetailTextView

best regards,

Patrick

```
class PersonDetailsView: UITableViewController {
    
    let redirector = Redirector(behavior: .doNotFollow)
    let RequestUrl = "https://apiurlexample.com/api" 
    var personID:String = ""
    
    var schedules: [cardResult]?
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewData: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        GetCardNumbers()
    }
    
    class cardResult: XMLMappable {
        
        var nodeName: String!
        
        var error: String?
        var cardrowset: cardRowset?
        
        required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
        
        func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
            error <- map.attributes["error"]
            cardrowset <- map["ROWSET"]
        }
    }
    //
    
    class cardRowset: XMLMappable {
        var nodeName: String!
        
        var cardrows: [cardRow]?
        
        required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
        
        func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
            cardrows <- map["ROW"]
        }
    }
    
    class cardRow: XMLMappable {
        var nodeName: String!
        
        var rcn: String?
        var valid: String?
        
        required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
        
        func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
            rcn <- map["IDNR"]
            valid <- map["VALIDITY"]
        }
    }
    
    func GetCardNumbers() {
        
        //
        class personDetails: XMLMappable {
            var nodeName: String!
            var sql: String?
            
            init() {}
            
            required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
            
            func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
                sql <- (map["sql"], XMLCDATATransform())
            }
        }
        
        let persondetails = personDetails()
        persondetails.nodeName = "query"
        persondetails.sql = "select IDNR, Validity from accesskey WHERE personid=\(personID)"
        
        
        AF.request(RequestUrl, method: .post, parameters: persondetails.toXML(), encoding: XMLEncoding.default)
            .redirect(using: redirector)
            .responseXMLObject { (response: DataResponse<cardResult, AFError>) in
                
                
                switch response.result {
                
                case .success(let value):
                    
                    debugPrint(value)
                    print("AF-Success")
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    
                    print("AF-Error")
                    print(error)
                    
                }
            }
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // return the number of rows
        return 5
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let person = schedules?[indexPath.row].cardrowset?.cardrows
        cell.textLabel?.text = person?[indexPath.row].valid

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Aren't you just missing a tableViewData.reloadData() after receiving the xml data?

Comment: I'm receiving a fatal error when reloading the data:

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: pretty sure that's because of the fixed number of cells (return 5) while you may not always have data to display 5 rows. It should be something along `return schedules?.count ?? 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is always better to follow Swift's [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming):

> Follow case conventions. Names of types and protocols are
> **UpperCamelCase**. Everything else is **lowerCamelCase**.

Also, to display, in your `UITableView`, the array of `CardRow` elements you need to hold that array inside your view controller. Instead of that you are declaring an array of `CardResult` elements which is not right because there is only one `CardResult` object.

That being said, your view controller should be like this:

```
class PersonDetailsView: UITableViewController {
    
    let redirector = Redirector(behavior: .doNotFollow)
    let requestUrl = "https://apiurlexample.com/api"
    var personID: String = ""
    
    var cardRows: [CardRow] = []
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewData: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        getCardNumbers()
    }
    
    class CardResult: XMLMappable {
        var nodeName: String!
        
        var error: String?
        var cardrowset: CardRowset?
        
        required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
        
        func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
            error <- map.attributes["error"]
            cardrowset <- map["ROWSET"]
        }
    }
    
    class CardRowset: XMLMappable {
        var nodeName: String!
        
        var cardrows: [CardRow]?
        
        required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
        
        func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
            cardrows <- map["ROW"]
        }
    }
    
    class CardRow: XMLMappable {
        var nodeName: String!
        
        var rcn: String?
        var valid: String?
        
        required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
        
        func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
            rcn <- map["IDNR"]
            valid <- map["VALIDITY"]
        }
    }
    
    func getCardNumbers() {
        class PersonDetails: XMLMappable {
            var nodeName: String!
            var sql: String?
            
            init() {}
            
            required init?(map: XMLMap) {}
            
            func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
                sql <- (map["sql"], XMLCDATATransform())
            }
        }
        
        let persondetails = PersonDetails()
        persondetails.nodeName = "query"
        persondetails.sql = "select IDNR, Validity from accesskey WHERE personid=\(personID)"
        
        
        AF.request(requestUrl, method: .post, parameters: persondetails.toXML(), encoding: XMLEncoding.default)
            .redirect(using: redirector)
            .responseXMLObject { (response: DataResponse<CardResult, AFError>) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    debugPrint(value)
                    print("AF-Success")
                    
                    self.cardRows = value.cardrowset?.cardrows ?? []
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("AF-Error")
                    print(error)
                }
            }
    }
    
    // numberOfSections(in:) doesn't actually needed here since by default UITableView has one section
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Here you need to return the count of the cardRows array
        return cardRows.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let person = cardRows[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = person.valid

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Gcharita, thanks for your reply. this results on a fatal error on the indexPath.row *thread 1: Fatal error: index out of range.

Comment: @patrickb100 make sure that you return the `count` of the `cardRows` array in `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` function. I think that this is your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! the issue is solved now